# ViewPagerAdapter Toolbar scrollable horizontaly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a toolbar with many tabs, but when there is too much tabs, text inside is splitted and all the tabs are on my screen. 
I want my toolbar to be scrollable but can't do it myself.

There is my Layout :

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

            />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried to replace the appbarlayout by a NestedScrollView but don't work.
Thank's for your help.

---

[image]

You can see that the names of the tabs are splitted because there is too much tabs. I want the size of the toolbar to be adjusted to the tabs and I can't scroll horizontaly in the tabLayout.

Comment: May be you need to use TabLayout instead of/along with Toolbar

Comment: @RahulShukla how ?

Comment: Follow the official docs at https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Comment: @RahulShukla No way to do this with my AppBarLayout ?

Comment: I believe, you want to hide the Tabs when the user scrolls the pages upwards, right? This effect is easily achievable and you can find numerous example on Google.

Comment: @RahulShukla no it's not what I want, I will put a screen of my case to show u. Don't find the words to explain ^^

Comment: @RahulShukla it's done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206695/discussion-between-rahul-shukla-and-neokerd).

Comment: @RahulShukla Sry I was AFK, can u come back ? thx